# TFS2012 / IIS7.5 and Windows authorize

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I develop web app, which cooperates with to TFS2012. In my local machine its works fine, but when i deploy on server i get the following exception:

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6440920
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, WebException& webException) +195

My connect to TFS Code:

```
            _collection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://xxx/tfs/TestPrjects/"));
            _collection.EnsureAuthenticated();
            _store = _collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

my web-config:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  ...
<system.web>
```

in ISS i activate Windows authorization:

[image]

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The details you are using to access TFS are incorrect.

The reason it works on your local machine is because the webserver is running as you, who has access to TFS.  On the IIS server it's running as the app pool user, which won't have access.

### Potential Solutions

**Run the app pool as a user that has access to TFS (or grant the current user access)**
This is ok for read only access, but if you're writing back to items you may want to not go down this route

**Enable delegation so the code that connects to TFS is run as the currently authenticated windows user**
This is much harder to do and only works in internet explorer out of the box.  Firefox users can change a setting and Chrome users need to start chrome with a commandline switch.

wrap a using(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate()) {} around your code that uses TFS and ensure you are using CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials to connect to TFS.

**Use the TFS Server API**
Be naughty and  use server instead of the client api.  The server API writes directly to the db and doesn't need to impersonate a user.  I highly doubt this is a supported path and you won't find much information on it.  However it still needs to run as a user with access to the db (like option 1, but supports updates as windows authed users)